# SVN Relocate - UUID error

Tags: svn

I've copied my repository to the new server.

In the meantime, I've made some changes on my project, so I want to post a Commit to the new server.

I've changed the svn UUID on the new server to be the same as it is on the old server - `1c8601b0-280a-384e-84ca-1910148bfb83`.

When I'm in the project folder, I set the `TortoiseSVN > Relocate` and I pass the new server's URL. THen I get the error:

[image]

I'm wondering why I get this error because taking into account that the UUIDs (`1c8601b0-280a-384e-84ca-1910148bfb83`) are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want you want to force subversion to use the same UUID for the new repository as the old repository, you need to add `--force-uuid` to your `svnadmin load` command.

Or you could do as follows:

1. Create repository archive with all the contents.
2. Transfer archive to another server
3. Extract archive at the target server
4. Run `svnadmin` using `-r` property with the value having path to extracted repository.

In other words, just copy repository contents and transfer it to the proper destination.