# Moving my SVN to Assembla, from local, given UUID error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804112/svn-relocate-uuid-error), and am ready to use `--force-uuid`.

However, my programmer suggested that I could also do a fresh checkout on my server, just in case Assembla and the existing TortoiseSVN format aren't identical (moving to Assembla, let's be fresh/clean).

I'm not totally comfortalbe doing that, because I didn't initially set up the SVN myself and am not fluent in server/SVN management.

Is there any possible damage or risk to forcing the UUID to match?

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's separate out the ***client*** from the ***server***...

I am assuming that Assembla is where your repository is stored. This is your Subversion ***server***.

TortoiseSVN is the software you're using to checkout the software from your server. This is your ***client***.

First, let's talk about the ***server***.

Each Subversion repository that is on your server has what is called a *Universally Unique Identifier* (UUID). This is created when you create the Subversion repository. How does Subversion generate the UUID and know that there is absolutely no other in the Subversion repository in the entire world that doesn't share this UUID? It really doesn't, but it's not very likely that there's another Subversion repository with the UUID. The UUID is [generated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1) based upon the time, the IP address, and the MAC address, plus some pseudo-random values.

Since the UUID is guaranteed to be unique for any Subversion repository in the entire world, your Subversion client can use it to make sure it's talking to the same repository that you did your original checkout from.

When you move your Subversion repository from one location to another, you have to create a new Subversion repository where you can load in your data. Since this is really the same repository as before, the Subversion load command allows you to reset the new Subversion repository's UUID to be the same as the old.

Notice this is done:

1. On the server
2. At the time you import your data into the repository

This is not done by your client software since this is the ***server side*** of the issue.

---

Now, we're going to talk about your Subversion ***client*** which in this case is TortoiseSVN

When a Subversion client does a checkout into a working directory, it keeps track of the URL from where you did the checkout, and the UUID of that repository.

Let's take a look at your working directory using TortoiseSVN. Right click on your Subversion checkout folder, and select *Properties* on the bottom of the drop-down context menu. **Don't go into the TortoiseSVN sub-menu!** Select the *Properties* menu item from the bottom of the context menu.

Click on the *Subversion* tab. You'll see several pieces of information. Two of them are the URL where the checkout occurred, and the UUID of the repository.

When you right-click on the checkout folder and do a TortoiseSVN->Relocate, you can change the URL where the checkout occurred. However, you cannot ever change the UUID for that checkout.

That's because your Subversion client is using this to make sure that even if you've moved your Subversion repository to a new server, you're talking to the same repository.

---

What can you do if you've moved your repository, but didn't make sure the UUID is the same? Here are several solutions from best to worst.

- Do a new, fresh checkout. This is the ***BEST*** option. Before you moved your Subversion repository, you should have checked in all of your changes. If not, you can use the Status to find your changes and copy them to your new, fresh checkout.
- Reload the repository with the old dump file and this time make sure you use the `--force-uuid` flag.
- It is possible to change the UUID on the Subversion server by manually editing the UUID. The Subversion server's UUID is stored in the db/uuid file on the server. You can find the old UUID in an old checkout (see above). Simply change the UUID in the db/uuid file inside the Subversion repository directory. Remember one false move and you completely destroy your ability to ever read your repository again. Your company will lose the entire source code, go bankrupt, and everyone at your work will lose their job and hate you forever. No pressure.
- Hack your Subversion checkout to change the UUID to the new UUID. The UUID is in the `.svn\entries` file in each and everyone of your directories you've checked out. If you're using Subversion 1.7 based clients, all bets are off. I believe the UUID might be encrypted. This might work, but then it might create a corrupted checkout that will end up damaging the master repository if you attempt to commit your changes.

Comment: Very thorough, David, thank you!  To take my process to the next step - I've checked out a fresh copy locally on my PC through TortoiseSVN.  The programmers uploaded the latest version to assembla, and I'm set to run SVNup on my live server.  Before I do this, I need to run svn switch --relocate [old location] [assembla location].  I enter in the correct id/passwords for assembla, and all starts to perform as normal.  Then, it hits me with the incorrect UUID message.  Appologies for being slow (overly cautious), but this is the point when I run --force-uuid, correct?

Comment: @user900456 - I'm confused. Did you create the new repository? Why are the developers using the old one? You can use `svnadmin dump` to dump out the transactions from the old repository and `svnadmin load` to move them to the new repository. If you are using a new repository, and you need to move what the devs committed to the old, you do two checkouts in two locations; One from the new and one from the old. Then, manually copy the files from the old to the new, and commit to the new. Why are the devs using the old repo?

Comment: We're all using a new repository.  Before moving to Assembla they did a fresh check out, then moved the last build to the Assembla server.  The issue, (I belive but could be wrong), is on the live server.  When I run SVN UP (between Assembla and the live server) it hits me with the error.  Sorry for the slow response (I've been out of town).  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: A new repository has not been created on the live server, only locally and on assembla.  I was hoping to avoid doing this.

Comment: When you say _locally_, are you talking about a ***server*** or a ***client*** instance? You talk about the _live server_ and _Assembla_. Is the _live server_ a Subversion server or a server where you deploy your software? Assmebla to me is a place where version control repositories are stored. Are we talking about the same thing? I believe we might be getting terminology mixed up.

Comment: I agree David, appologies as I should have clarified this earlier.  There are three locations involved.  **bold**Locally**bold** = my PC (or the programmer's PCs, they work in a remote location), **bold**Assembla**bold** is where the we all commit changes, where the repositories are stored, and the **bold**live server**bold** is our server in the US.  Everything locally and on Assembla is current to the most recent revision, build with a fresh check out.  The live server is where the point of concern is (UUID issue), and where I log in to through SSH and run SVN UP.

Comment: Since moving to Assembla I haven't touched anything on the live server.  1. Because I'm on the road and the hotel connection is weak, 2. Due to the UUID message, I don't want to do anything I'm not familiar with, that may cause issues that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @ryan - So, the problem is that your PC's working copy is having problems. The solution is to do a new clean checkout, then copy the files from the old checkout area to the new one (be careful not to copy over the `.svn` or `_svn` folders). Now, commit your changes from the new checkout area and delete the old one. You cannot use `--force-uuid` on your PC.

Comment: No, my PC copy is running fine, it's the live server that's giving me the UUID warning.  Both local and assembla are new/clean check outs and syncronized.  I just need to commit the latest version from assembla to my live server, but since everything except the live version is fresh, the live version issues the warning.